# File download not work in mobile

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I use this code for download from link to sdcard

This code worked full in emulator but not work in mobile

In mobile file created but capacity of file is zero and not downloading full

How can fixed it ?!

**NOTE : i understand my code not work for 4 version, what is problem ?!**

Thx

```
public class FileDownloader {

    public static void download(final String downloadPath, final String filepath, final OnProgressDownloadListener listener) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(downloadPath);

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.connect();

                    int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();

                    File file = new File(filepath);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        file.delete();
                    }

                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[G.DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
                    int len = 0;
                    int downloadedSize = 0;
                    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        downloadedSize += len;
                        final float downloadPercent = 100.0f * (float) downloadedSize / fileSize;
                        Log.i("PER", "" + downloadPercent);

                        if (listener != null) {
                            G.HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    listener.onProgressDownload((int) downloadPercent);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    outputStream.close();
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove this line and worked full :

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```